# Designing a large LOB Solution in Visual Studio 2014

Tags: vb.net

I have an Business Application which I am re-writing in VB.NET - currently in VB6.
The data is stored in SQL Server across nearly 200 tables, 60 of which hold Cross-reference Tables (Customers, Staff etc. etc.). The rest deal with Customer Job Data, Workshop Activity, Human Resource (Time sheets/Absenteeism etc.), Fleet Management plus other smaller sections - most of which need to interact with each other in some way. In the current application (VB6), I had to split out some sections into separate executables, which obviously ruined the interaction. To give you some idea of size, here are the following: Setting up the Cross-reference section involves 138 forms, Customer Job Data - 250 forms, plus 60+ forms for the remaining. My hope is that I will be able to build this application, split into appropriate Projects/Classes, within a single VS Solution . Any advice from those of you that have experience of this size of application would be very much appreciated. Best regards.

Comment: What do you want know exactly? Yes it is possible to split your single project in many subprojects all compiled from the same solution, But without knowing any details of the logic of your application it is a wild guess to give any reasonable answer.

Comment: "Customer Job Data, Workshop Activity, Human Resource . . . " it sounds like your project already breaks down naturally into different apps for different job functions.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Yes, the Solution is broken down into the sections I described with the appropriate data access and business logic layers also. My question is whether all this lumped into a single Solution is the way to go, or are there problems of performance etc. ahead that I am going to have to deal with? Thanks again.

Comment: IME you won't hit performance problems simply because of the size of the exe or number of tables in the database - in typical business apps, it's all about the efficiency of each individual query and how much data it pulls back.

Comment: Thanks for your replies